# Using ajax to save ID from Facebook api to mysql but getting wrong value

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, facebook

Ok, I know the title is confusing so any suggestions on making it better would be helpful.

Anyway, I am using PHP, MySQL, ajax with jQuery, and the js Facebook api. When a user logs in to my app using the Facebook api, I am saving some info about that user to the database. The info is their user id, their user access token, each page they can edit, and the associated page's access token.

Everything is working great and getting saved to the database except for the user id. A number is getting saved for the user id but not the correct number. I have no idea where the number is coming from.

In my database, the id is a BIGINT if that matters.

Here is my js:

```
FB.api('/me/accounts',function(apiresponse){
    console.log("user id: "+response.authResponse.userID);
    var data=apiresponse['data'];
    var fbUserId = response.authResponse.userID;
    var fbUserAt = response.authResponse.accessToken;
    var ids = new Array();
    var pages = new Array();
    var pageAccessToken = new Array();

    console.log(apiresponse);

    for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        ids[i]=data[i].id;
        pages[i]=data[i].name;
        pageAccessToken[i]=data[i].access_token;
        alert(fbUserId);
        jQuery.ajax({
          type: "POST",
          url: my_ajax.ajaxurl,
          data: {
              'action': 'dallas_db_facebook_pages_insert',
              'fb_user_id': fbUserId,
              'fb_user_access_token': fbUserAt,
              'fb_user_page_id': ids[i],
              'fb_user_page_access_token': pageAccessToken[i]
          },
          beforeSend: function() {
          },
          success: function(html){
            console.log('success');
          },
          error: function(){
            console.log('error')
          },

       });

        jQuery('<option/>').val(data[i].id).html(data[i].name).appendTo('.pagesdropdown');
    }
```

Here is my PHP (WordPress) function:

```
function dallas_db_facebook_pages_insert () {
    global $wpdb;
    $table_name = $wpdb->prefix . 'dallas_facebook_user';
    $fb_user_id = $_POST['fb_user_id'];
    $fb_user_access_token = $_POST['fb_user_access_token'];
    $fb_user_page_id = $_POST['fb_user_page_id'];
    $fb_user_page_access_token = $_POST['fb_user_page_access_token'];

    $wpdb->insert(
        $table_name,
        array(
            'user_id'                => $fb_user_id,
            'user_access_token'      => $fb_user_access_token,
            'user_page_id'           => $fb_user_page_id,
            'user_page_access_token' => $fb_user_page_access_token
        )
    );
}
```

Comment: What is the number?

Comment: The number that is added to database is 2147483647.

Comment: And that particular number doesn't sound familiar ...? It's not a problem on the database end, but in your JavaScript - it doesn't handle integers that large, so make sure you treat them as strings in all places. // Facebook IDs should be stored as VARCHAR anyway. Facebook says they are "alphanumeric strings"; they might contain only digits now, but that could change at any point in the future.